How to solve "Cannot use import statement outside a module" error from AWS Lambda deployed with CDK
I am using the AWS CDK (v2.140.0) to deploy a single lambda function written in ES6 javascript and with a Node v20.x runtime. The root of the project contains a package.json file in which I am defining "type": "module".  I am using aws CDK and SDK packages but otherwise am not consuming any 3rd party libraries in my application code.
My file structure looks like:
bin
  cdk.js
lib
  my-stack.js
src
  index.js
package.json
cdk.json

I am able to successfully synth and deploy the lambda to AWS.  The lambda runs on an Eventbridge schedule and is invoked at the correct times.
However, I am getting the following error in Cloudwatch: SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
My index.js file is written as:
import { foo } from './foo-service.js';

export const handler = async () => {
  // do stuff with foo
};


I have gone down a few rabbit holes and tried most of the suggestions from this SO post without any success.

changing my index.js file to a index.mjs
using the "node" specific CDK construct
creating an additional package.json file within the src directory and defining "type": "module"

Any insight or guidance is much appreciated.

Are you sure you saw the same error message when you renamed index.js to index.mjs (and redeployed the function)? I'd expect, at worst, an import error but not a syntax error.

Yes, I did receive the exact same error, which I also thought was odd.

A simple test with index.mjs and foo.mjs with the former importing a function from the latter via import { somefunc } from "./foo.mjs" works fine, imports the function, and the exported function is callable. Also, make sure you re-deploy the Lambda function after making changes.

I appreciate the suggestion.  I did as you asked, updated my .js files to .mjs files, updated the paths, redeployed, and unfortunately, am getting the same exact syntax error as before.

Can you take CDK etc. out of the equation. Just create a trivial Node.js v20 index.mjs and foo.mjs, with the latter exporting a function and the former importing that function, as shown above. Use the AWS console to do this, not your current deployment automation.

Starting with Node.js 18, Lambda searches folders in the NODE_PATH environment variable when loading ES modules. What is the value of that?

@jarmod - Yes, doing a basic deploy straight from the AWS console does work as you've suggested.  I did just notice that the code I deployed via the CDK is only showing the index.js file in the file tree. None of the sibling files.  I'm not sure if that is "normal" or not but it seems wrong.
@morganney - I have no ENV vars configured for this function per my deployment setup.

I ended up changing my cdk syntax a bit.  I was using Lambda.InlineCode originally but then I switched to Lambda.Code.fromAsset I am now able to get all the applicable files deployed.  I'm now getting a different error which I think is related to the fact that I'm using an out of the box version of "fetch" which, despite working when I create a lambda from scratch in the console, does not work for my CDK version.

Ultimately my issue came from following an AWS tutorial in which the lambda function was contained entirely within a single index.js file, and in my case my handler required modules outside of that file.  I needed to change my cdk implementation to:
    // BEFORE
    const lambdaFn = new Lambda.Function(this, 'lambda-id', {
      runtime: Lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_20_X,
      handler: 'index.handler',
      code: new Lambda.InlineCode(fs.readFileSync('./src/index.js', { encoding: 'utf-8' }))
    });

    // AFTER
    const lambdaFn = new Lambda.Function(this, 'lambda-id', {
      runtime: Lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_20_X,
      handler: 'index.handler',
      code: Lambda.Code.fromAsset('./src', { exclude: ['*.js'] })
    });

